# reading from table in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

with the code below i let people fill in how many pizza's they want and then pass the chosen pizza ids through the url using get.

```
<?php // some code that connects to database ?>
<table>

        <form method="get" action="oder_process.php">
                <?php
                while (list($pizzaId, $pizzaName, $pizzaNumber, $pizzaPrice) = mysql_fetch_row($resultaat))
                        {

                            echo        "<tr>
                                        <td>".$pizzaName."</td>
                                        <td>".$pizzaNumber."</td>
                                        <td>".$pizzaPrice."</td> 
                                        <td> <input type='text' name='pizzas[$pizzaId]'                   value='$qty' size='3' /></td>
                                        </tr>";
                        }
                mysql_close($db);        
                ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Bestel!" />
        </form>
    </table>
```

Now displaying the pizza id with the amount filled in works just fine. But then I also want to read other columns like pizza name or description from the database. However what i'm doing below doesn't do it. Any ideas?
part of the order_process.php file:

```
echo "Your order: <br />";


            foreach ($_GET['pizzas'] as $pizzaId => $qty)    
            {
                if ($qty > 0)
                echo $pizzaId." ".$qty."<br />";
                $pizzaSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pizzas where pizza_id =       $pizzaId");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pizzaSql))
                {
                    echo $row['pizza_name'];
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is it doing? If pizza_name is a field in pizzas, I can't imagine why this wouldn't work.

Comment: "doesn't do it"? Can you be more specific? what happens when you print_r($row) inside the while loop? Does it not show all the data?

Comment: Is `pizza_id` a numeric field in DB?

Comment: @Bob Baddeley: doesn't do it means it prints nothing. when i print_r($row) inside the loop it simply shows all records instead of only the ones where a an amount of pizzas is filled in. 
@bazmegakapa: yes it is its an int(11)

Comment: Also, add the structure of a table. Please keep in mind, don't use Stackoverflow as a FORUM, you should come here when you don't get an answer for your search & don't make us to teach you basics dude.

Comment: @Rakesh putting it in table tags is not going to make a difference in the logic i'm struggling with here

Comment: if it's showing all records, then your pizzaIDs are not correct. We'd need to know what $_GET['pizzas'] is.

Comment: `$_GET['pizzas']`  is an assoc array with attributes from the input element, being pizzaid and qty as key => value. now i'm only taking the pizzaid of the ones where the value of qty is larger than zero. you can see that in my if statement. my codeline                 `echo $pizzaId." ".$qty."<br />";` proves this because it only shows the pizzaid and the qty of the fields of my input element where a number is filled in. now, since i've done that selection i want to use the chosen pizzaid's in a sql statement and read the records based on the chosen pizzaids and that's where i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

why foreach()?  can't you just ...

```
if ( is_numeric( $_GET['pizzaid'] ) ) {
    $pizzaSql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE pizza_id=%d",$_GET['pizzaid']);
    $pizzaQuery = mysql_query($pizzaSql);
    $numPizzas = mysql_num_rows( $pizzaQuery );
    while ( $order = mysql_fetch_array($pizzaQuery,MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
        if ( $numPizzas > 0 ) {
            echo $orderVariables;
        } else {
            echo 'Error: no order exists for that ID thingy';
        }
    }
}
```

i added some minor validation that assumes the pizza/order id is a numeric value.  i don't trust anything that comes into a script from the $_GET array without some serious data validation first

Answer (score 0):

can you try chucking in a test to make sure the query worked as expected

```
$pizzaSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pizzas where pizza_id = $pizzaId");

if (mysql_error()) {
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the iput. Put the if statement there but the query seems fine.